# New object reference for pass by reference in Java

Tags: java, object

Class 1

```
private void checkDuplicateCustomer(BulkCustomerVO bulkCustomerVO) {
    PagedDuplicateCustomerVO duplicateCustomerVO = new PagedDuplicateCustomerVO();
    duplicateCustomerVO.setCustomer(bulkCustomerVO.getCustomerVO());
    duplicateCustomerVO = getCustomerBO().getDuplicateCustomerDetails(duplicateCustomerVO);
    if (!MyUtils.isNull(duplicateCustomerVO)) {
        if (duplicateCustomerVO.isValid()) {

             // some operation
            bulkCustomerVO.setErrorDetals(...........)

        }

    }
}
```

Class 2

```
public PagedDuplicateCustomerVO getDuplicateCustomerDetails(PagedDuplicateCustomerVO pagedDuplicateCustomer) {
    PagedDuplicateCustomerVO pagedDuplicateCustomerVO = pagedDuplicateCustomer;

        // some operation that changes customerVO reference in pagedDuplicateCustomer

    }
}
```

In the above scenario, `BulkCustomerVO` has `CustomerVO` instance. It is set to `PagedDuplicateCustomerVO`  and passed as argument
to `getDuplicateCustomerDetails()` method where it is getting changed. Those changes affect my flow in `checkDuplicateCustomer` method.

What I want to do is create a separate `customerVO` instance from `bulkCustomerVO.getCustomerVO()` in `checkDuplicateCustomer` which is specific for the `getDuplicateCustomerDetails` so any changes in second class wont affect my flow in class 1.

What I can do it copy all the fields from `bulkCustomerVO.getCustomerVO()` to new `CustomerVO`, but VO is huge and I dont want to do that. It will be a unwanted code in my class.

so, How can I approach this scenario?

EDIT- I cannot use clone coz this will lead to a over head of changing my VO's to implement cloneable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. Bu using clone utiles of SerializationUtils.

```
duplicateCustomerVO.setCustomer((CustomerVO) SerializationUtils
                .clone(bulkCustomerVO.getCustomerVO()));
```

Answer (score 3):

See http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)

Maybe this is what you want.

==================

```
public PagedDuplicateCustomerVO getDuplicateCustomerDetails(PagedDuplicateCustomerVO pagedDuplicateCustomer) {

    CustomerVO customer = new CustomerVO();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(customer, pagedDuplicateCustomer.getCustomerVO());
    pagedDuplicateCustomer.setCustomer(customer);
    return pagedDuplicateCustomer;

}
```

Comment: +1 for my today's learning :-) Any idea if it will be shallow or deep clone.

Comment: @ejb_guy I think using `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` is a good way to doing shallow clone.To deep cloning a object,I think use java serialization interface is the effective way.

Comment: @ejb_guy Thanks for your solution. I tried implementing BeanUtils.copyProperties(), But still the reference is available. This is wat I ve tried `PagedDuplicateCustomerVO duplicateCustomerVO = new PagedDuplicateCustomerVO();
  CustomerVO customerVO = new CustomerVO();
  BeanUtils.copyProperties(customerVO, bulkCustomerVO.getCustomerVO());
  duplicateCustomerVO.setCustomer(customerVO);
  duplicateCustomerVO = getCustomerBO().getDuplicateCustomerDetails(
    duplicateCustomerVO);`

Comment: @om39a I think you should copy `customerVO` in the method `getDuplicateCustomerDetails()` and modify it.

Comment: @plucury customerVO is set in duplicateCustomerVO and it is sent to getDuplicateCustomerDetails(). Anyway it is going to be same!!

Comment: @plucury Yes!! I tried the above code which you have given. even I have mentioned it in my comment. But when I use it, still the reference is getting passed.

Comment: @om39a In java,Objects could only passed by reference.So what we can do is only refer it to another object.

Comment: @plucury But, I don't need reference object.. I need a new object which is similar to the old one with no reference to it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12548/discussion-between-om39a-and-plucury)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the cloning. For this your `PagedDuplicateCustomerVO` has to implement interface Clonnable interface. Then you can call the clone method on the object to get the shallow clone.